# Somewhat complex page to PDF (html, css, react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, pdf

I got a somewhat complex page I need to output to PDF format without forcing the user to use a print preview type screen to "Save as PDF". It's a Laravel web app that has a dedicated page formatted to be printed, but I need to generate a PDF without having to show the page. It uses bootstrap, css, a highcharts.js chart and a react component (already bundled).

Does anyone know of a way to turn this into a wysiwyg type PDF? I think I mainly need something that can take html, css, and js and be able to generate a PDF out of it but I haven't found anything.

Comment: After quick google search I found this, http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/of8k44w2/    and  https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40382   from highChart website